# how to take specific value from sql array result and use it as a parameter in another sql statement in php

Tags: php, arrays, web-services

i need some help ,please.
i have a sql statment that gives array of result

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM chat_messages WHERE sender_email='".$user_id."' OR receiver_email='".$user_id."' ORDER BY date_time DESC";
```

and its result like that

```
:[
    {"id":"47","sender_email":"amalkronz@hotmail.com","receiver_email":"test@test.com","message":"hee","date_time":"1456320044336"},
    {"id":"46","sender_email":"amalkronz@hotmail.com","receiver_email":"amalkronz@gmail.com","message":"hello","date_time":"1456319938285"},
    {"id":"45","sender_email":"amalkronz@hotmail.com","receiver_email":"amalkronz@gmail.com","message":"hi","date_time":"1456319929258"}
]
```

and i want to take the "sender_email" from each row and use it in another sql statement to get the user profile details and the same with the "receiver_email" 
how i can do that to get json response like that :

```
{ "success":true,"messages":[
      {"id":"156","sender_email":"sescooo@gmail.com","receiver_email":"jmaelagha@gmail.com","message":"hi","date_time":"1448660829608","sender":{"username":"test","img":"http:\/\/orchidatech.com\/sharearide\/images\/default_image.jpg","Gender":"","phone":"0049704197602","email":"sescooo@gmail.com","id":"101"},"receiver":{"username":"jmaagha agha","img":"https:\/\/lh5.googleusercontent.com\/-Ug34apPklis\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAD0\/QUjGOKH0qsU\/photo.jpg?sz=50","Gender":"","phone":"0595114000","email":"jmaelagha@gmail.com","id":"98"}},
      {"id":"155","sender_email":"jma@gmail.com","receiver_email":"seo@gmail.com","message":"hi","date_time":"1448660780012","sender":{"username":"jmaagha agha","img":"https:photo.jpgsz=50","Gender":"","phone":"0595114000","email":"jma@gmail.com","id":"98"},"receiver":{"username":"test","img":"http:default_image.jpg","Gender":"","phone":"0049704197602","email":"seo@gmail.com","id":"101"}},
      {"id":"154","sender_email":"jma@gmail.com","receiver_email":"seo@gmail.com","message":"hi ahmed","date_time":"1448660747317","sender":{"username":"jma agha","img":"https:photo.jpg?sz=50","Gender":"","phone":"0595114000","email":"jma@gmail.com","id":"98"},"receiver":{"username":"test","img":"http:default_image.jpg","Gender":"","phone":"0049704197602","email":"seo@gmail.com","id":"101"}}
    ]
}
```

P.S.: the server doesn't support the  mysqli fetch_all()
thanks

[image: chat table]

[image: user table]

Comment: without seeing your db schema it is hard to say but you can probably do that all in the initial sql with some table joins

Answer (score 0):

You must loop over a query result that contains multiple rows. Take this example:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `sometable`"); //multiple rows returned
$savedValues = array();
while($nextRow = $mysqli->fetch_assoc()){
    $someValue = $nextRow['YourEmail_Column_name'];
    array_push($savedValues, $someValue);
}

$len = count($savedValues);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
    $newQuery = "SELECT * FROM `someothertable` WHERE `email` = '$savedValues[$i]'";
    $mysqli->query($newQuery);
    $result = $mysqli->fetch_assoc(); //here is your row.  repeat above step for multiple rows!
}
```

Hope this helps you out!

PS: This could take up lots of memory in PHP, to solve this, perhaps use slimmer mysql statements based on conditions that you know will be true (or false).

Comment: i have small knowledge in php structure ,your solution give me result from only the second table the user  profile table but not give me the chat table element from the first query,
i will edit my question to be include the db structure